# image slider going over 100% width

Tags: html, css, slider

i have an image slider that is 100% of the page width, here is my code:

```
.ei-slider{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:2px #f36f25 dashed;
}
.ei-slider-loading{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
}
.ei-slider-large{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ei-slider-large li{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.ei-slider-large li img{
    width: 100%;
}
.ei-title{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 13%;
    top: 30%;
}
.ei-title h2, .ei-title h3{
    text-align: right;
}
.ei-title h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #b5b5b5;
}
.ei-title h3{
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs{
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li.ei-slider-element{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li a{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    background: #666 ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
        0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li a:hover{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-box-reflect: 
        below 0px -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            left bottom, 
            from(transparent), 
            color-stop(50%, transparent), 
            to(rgba(255,255,255,0.3))
            );
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img{
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 13px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}
@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    .ei-title{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    .ei-title h2, .ei-title h3{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .ei-title h2{
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
    .ei-title h3{
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
}
```

im not sure why, but there is a horizontal scroll bar which i dont want.

i have also created a fiddle for this so you can see the HTML code aswell as the CSS

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/827kN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons for this that I see from the code above.

1. A reset to the browser's default padding/margins to elements (which you may or may have not done already) may be needed

   `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`
2. Your element has `width: 100%` but also has a 2px border .. which adds to that and goes beyond 100% width.
   Here's an example using inset box shadow instead - http://jsfiddle.net/827kN/6/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (which I don't fully understand) in my browser (latest firefox) there is a System attribute being applied to the inner ul which is adding padding of 40px.

You can fix it (and probably try fathom why it is being applied using the following modified css

```
.ei-slider-large {
  -moz-padding-start: 0;//<<-- this is the offending style so setting it to 0 sorts out your problem
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I should imagine you may want to apply a css reset (which should remove all padding and standardise the css to give you a decent starting base css) - try Eric Meyers css reset

Comment: If you add -moz-padding-start to the style to override then you should also add all the other browser specific versions of that css (i.e. for Safari, Opera, etc)